# android copy mp3 file success but duration not change

Tags: java, android, file

i try to copy mp3 file in external storage and limit duration of new file. it work but when it started, although i run to limit time, it still display end time like old file.

```
 private void copy(File in, File out) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(in);
            os = new FileOutputStream(out);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0 && out.length()<175642) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            assert is != null;
            is.close();
            assert os != null;
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

how can i fix it. i really expect your help. **have a nice day,everyone!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cut of the rest of the file. This leads to a kind of corrupted file because the data in the header-block (e.g. the length) is no longer correct.

For some information about the mp3 file format:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3

I highly recommend to adjust the header information after shortening the file.